# Long running SQL Server reports, how to run them in async mode

Tags: .net, sql-server, asynchronous, rdlc, reportviewer

I have some long running SQL Server reports that run for 10+ mins, 
How can I run them in async mode where they run and then alert the users that it is available.

I use SQL Server 2014 and reports run in .NET application in report viewer with Reports/RDLC. 
I am willing to change application but can't rewrite hundreds of reports and queries.
Queries have been optimized, so now only thing left is to make it ASync.

Comment: Tip research `await Task.Run()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some Pub/Sub or background jobs on the server-side, for example, you can use [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/) to schedule some background job (your report calculation), then when the job will be ready, you need somehow pass calculated data from server-side to client-side, for this you need in continuation of the job specify how this will be done, for example, this can be done using [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

If you don't want any third-party, this will be a little bit more tricky, for example, you can write custom Pub/Sub based on [channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/), or [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netcore-3.1), or whatever. Then on client-side, you will need to use some kind of long pulling using AJAX requests, or just WebSockets in order to retrieve the data from the server when it will be ready.